# No space left on device- on Amazon EC2 instance Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

I just expanded my storage space on Amazon EC2, after I ran out of volume. However, even after doing so, I receive an error message as follows:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-27:~/walt/bin$ LC_ALL=C 
sort -k 1,1 -k 3,3n -k 2,2n -k 6,6 \-o ./final_1_mr.mr.sorted_end_first ./final_1_mr.mr
*sort: write failed: /tmp/sort8Aua2D: No space left on device*
```

My storage statistics:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           799M  340K  799M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      788G  295G  462G  39% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
```

I'm doing my Master's project and stuck with this this error message. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: you are displaying the free inodes , not the free disk space, used `df -h` to display the free space and edit the post...also, how big are the file which you are trying to sort ?

Comment: Edited the post. Sorry about that. The files I'm trying to sort is about 4 GB.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `/tmp` is only 1Mb, while the file to be sorted is 4Gb. I don't know perfectly how `sort` works but it is surely using `/tmp` (as stated in the error) and the 1Mb is not enough.

You should create another partition and mount that in the `/tmp`, or if you can not do this, create a virtual disk of 10-20Gb (or bigger) with `fallocate` or `dd` in your home folder where you have enough space, and mount that as `/tmp`. `fallocate` is faster because it will not write the whole file like `dd`.

So, you should do the following to create a virtual disk in your home directory and mount it as `/tmp` :

```
cd                              # change to your home directory    
fallocate -l 10G mydrive.img    # create the virtual drive file
mkfs -t ext3 mydrive.img        # format the virtual drive
sudo umount /tmp                # unmount the /tmp
sudo mount -t auto -o loop mydrive.img /tmp   # mount the virtual drive
```

Maybe you could as well just `umount` the `/tmp` and use the existing `tmp` folder which is in the `/` root folder, as the `/` partition has a lot of space. Just make sure that after the `umount` the `/tmp` permits full access for everyone :

```
sudo umount /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: Probably want `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` so that the sticky bit is set.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what are the permissions of `/tmp` in this kind of scenario, so sticky bit is a good idea. Edited the post to reflect this

Comment: or just set `$TMPDIR`, or use `sort`'s `-T` or `--temporary-directory` option.  `/var/tmp`, perhaps.

Comment: @cas right, the best option !

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sort` specify `-T dir` (or `--temporary-directory=dir`) where `dir` is a writable directory on a filesystem with enough space, such as `/home/$USER/mytemp` for the layout you posted.